# Where do electrical charges go, on a nonconductor dielectric when we make it charged?

Tags: electrostatics, solid-state-physics, charge, dielectric

My question is about electrically nonconductor dielectrics. We know such materials don't possess free charges.They have atoms bound together and every atom has specific numbers of electrons turning around its nucleus.

When we make a dielectric charged:

where does this charge go?

what keeps the charge fixed on the structure?

Are they bound to specific atoms? If your answer is "yes",so What makes that atom specific to possess the charge?

(same questions about positively charging.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In most of the cases, the charge in dielectric material is created by imbalance in the charges existing in the dielectric. The dielectric is initially neutral. The balance is broken by certain “charging effects” such as friction, heat and pressure. The answer to which charging effect is responsible for the charge imbalance depends on the material and the surrounding conditions. Also in most cases the generation of a charge on a dielectric requires another body to be involved. With respect to the rest of your questions:

1.The charge doesn't go anywhere; it stays where it was generated. Charges can’t move in a    dielectric as you know.

2.The moving charges are mostly electrons, for electrons to move they need the necessary energy to overcome what is called the band gap.  For dielectrics the band gap is large such that the electrons require a lot of energy to overcome the gap to arrive to conduction band where they can move freely. See the picture [image: below]

3.Yes they are bounded to certain atoms, what makes those atoms specific is that they are the ones who experienced the imbalance of charges by the charging effects I mentioned above.

The same things can be said for positive or negative charges. Some dielectric materials have a tendency toward having negative charge when they are charged; some have a tendency toward having a positive charge. That tendency is determined by materials properties.
You can find a lot of information on this topic [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Static_electricity)

Comment: By the way, I know charges don't move in a dielectric medium, my question was about the place where they choose to locate(the atom that they will be bound to and its charactristics ). Thank you for your answer. I got it.